# Broadcom bcm4313 Ubuntu 13.10 connection time out

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, broadcom

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 I keep getting connection timed out every few seconds at which point i have to disconnect and reconnect to the WiFi network.

The WiFi card worked fine on 13.04 with the `bcmwl-kernel-source` installed but giving problems on 13.10:

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: c0:14:3d:cc:c9:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg 
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f0503fff
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv brcmsmac 
sudo modprobe -v wl
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However i got error `wl module not found`. continued with the steps but after reboot wifi could only find one network (not my own)

Comment: Copy and paste this command in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t)`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script`
It will download a script and create a file named wireless-info.tar.gz in your home folder with wireless information so we can see the condition of your wireless at this time and the Mac address, WPA key and WEP key are removed for your security,paste contents of the wireless-info.tar.gz file as a zip file at http://pastebin.com/. 
No internet
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: Here it is [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VT8QCGms)

Comment: I added a command you need to run then reboot.

Comment: Still not showing any wifi networks

Comment: Run the script again and post the new file to pastebin so we can see the changes.

Comment: Here is the second one [pasebin](http://pastebin.com/mR53ciYD)

Comment: Please do `sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac` does it come alive?

Comment: Nothing happens when i run it

Comment: Remove all wireless networks from network manager then reset your router and reboot computer.

Comment: Removed all the networks, rested the router, did a reboot didn't work. Then reran `sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac`. Still can't find any networks listed

Comment: There is a bug in this version of brcmsmac hopefully this will work since b43 is blacklisted, we may have to blacklist brcmsmac also. I change my answer.

Comment: Wifi works now. However the original problem returned.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.