# Broadcom BCM4313 wifi slow after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

I'm afraid this is another question about Broadcom wifi (in particular, the BCM4313 chipset). Before upgrading to 14.04, my wifi worked perfectly. Since upgrading, it has been working only very slowly, and occasionally not at all.

I am currently running the brcmsmac driver, which [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx), as well as many of the answers in the links below, suggest is the right one for my kernel version and chipset.

I have pasted the wireless info from my computer (including `lspci`, `iwconfig`, `iwlist`, `lsmod`, etc.) here: http://pastebin.com/5fhWiWi0.

I appreciate that problems such as mine seem to be widespread. Here are some of the similar questions I've found on these forums:

- [Extremely slow connection with a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450049/extremely-slow-connection-with-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card)
- [Cannot connect to wifi after upgrade to 13.10 (BCM4313)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405285/cannot-connect-to-wifi-after-upgrade-to-13-10-bcm4313)
- [Broadcom bcm4313 Ubuntu 13.10 connection time out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372374/broadcom-bcm4313-ubuntu-13-10-connection-time-out)
- [Wireless problems with Broadcom BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232049/wireless-problems-with-broadcom-bcm4313)
- [How do I get a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127633/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card-working)
- [13.10 BCM4313 network problems after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368448/13-10-bcm4313-network-problems-after-update)

However, none of the answers contained therein worked/applied in my case.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I have also tried using `bcmwl-kernel-source`. This works better than `bcrcmsmac` (but not perfectly) on one of the two wifi networks that I regularly use, but it won't even allow me to connect to the other one.

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-firmware-nonfree`. This is the common wifi driver containing package.

Comment: Done. Unfortunately no difference to the connection.

Comment: If so, install the broadcom b43 driver installer and install drivers from it. `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all (it won't even connect).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was having same issue with brcmsmac drivers.

I installed as given in the screenshot below.[image: Use synaptic and type broadcom in search box]
 Do not use jockey-gtk, it will fail to load there.

Install it in this way,

Reboot and your problem will be resolved. I was using 12.04 earlier and these proprietary drivers were not working there. But in 14.04 they are working flawlessly. If failed, try to install again as per broadcom documentation.

http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt

Read in last lines

From the GUI:

Package Manager (System>Administration>Synaptic Package Manager). Click the 
Reload button in the upper left corner of Synaptic to refresh your index then 
search for and reinstall the package named bcmwl-kernel-source.

From the shell:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Many thanks @Kanhinya. Apologies, I should have said in my original post that I've tried the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver and that doesn't work for me either. I've amended the question accordingly.